# Get first value of an array

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach, associative-array

I have an array:

```
Array (
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Pen
        [1] => Apple
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Oooo
        [1] => Pineapple pen
    )
```

How I can get a first elements of each array?

For example: Pen Oooo

It's my function

```
$parameters = array('wiki_1', 'wiki_2', 'wiki_3', 'wiki_4','wiki_5' ,'wiki_6', 'wiki_7', 'wiki_8', 'wiki_9', 'wiki_10', 'wiki_11', 'wiki_12');

function wiki_custom_fields( $parameters, $id ) {
        foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
           $wiki_result[] = get_post_custom_values($parameter, $id, true);
        }

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($wiki_result);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

If I use `print_r($wiki_result[][0]);` it's get 500 Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_column` function

```
$array =  array(
    array('Pen', 'Apple' ),
    array('Oooo', 'Pineapple pen')
);

$result = array_column($array, 0);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Pen
    [1] => Oooo
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use reset http://php.net/manual/es/function.reset.php

This function sets the internal pointer of the array to first element and also returns it.

`$first = reset($array)`

Comment: Also is more optimal than array_keys as if the array contains for example 1000 values, array_keys would generate an array of 1000 positions just to get the first element, with reset you Will not generate extra unused data that consumes memory.

Comment: Thanks. Almost got it, but it's looking now like this 
'Array ( [0] => Pen,  [1] => Apple )'
And I need to get 'Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Pen) [1] => Array (  [0] => Oooo ))'

Comment: $r = []; 
foreach($array as $k => $list){
   $r[$k]  = reset($list);
}

Comment: Sorry.
<code>
Array ( [0] => Pen, 
            [1] => Apple 
)
</code>
And I need to get
<code>
Array ( 
          [0] => Array ( 
                               [0] => Pen
          ) 
          [1] => Array ( 
                               [0] => Oooo 
           )
)
</code>

Comment: Then just $r[$k][] = reset($list)

Answer (score 0):

```
$param = array('first_key'=> 'First', 2, 3, 4, 5);
$keys   =   array_keys($param);
echo "Key = ".$keys[0];
```

example:

```
    $parameters = array('wiki_1', 'wiki_2', 'wiki_3', 'wiki_4','wiki_5' ,'wiki_6', 'wiki_7', 'wiki_8', 'wiki_9', 'wiki_10', 'wiki_11', 'wiki_12');

function wiki_custom_fields( $parameters, $id ) {
        foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
           $wiki_result[] = get_post_custom_values($parameter, $id, true);
        }

    $keys   =  array_keys($wiki_resul);
    echo "Key = ".$keys[0];
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r("Key = ".$keys[0]);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($elements as $elem){
    $result[] = $elem[0];
}
```

$result contains 'Pen', 'Oooo'.

The sintaxis `$result[]` is for adding a element to the last position in the array, the same as array_push (http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-push.php)

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
print_r($wiki_result[0]);
```

Comment: It's get only first element of an array.
'Array
(
    [0] => Pen
    [1] => Apple
)'

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I need a first element of each associative array.
See example in topic